# Ввод знака ударения и других интересных символов в Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, faq, xcompose

Как в Ubuntu наименее трудозатратным способом вводить символы, которых нет на клавиатуре?

Можно назначить клавишу Compose, онa же Multi_key.
Она дает всякие тире —,–, кавычки-елочки «», знак ударения ý и другие классные символы ☭,☺!
Например, <kbd>Multi_key</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd> печатает "—".
Но эти символы не всегда дружат с русской клавиатурой.

Файл `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose` содержит определения для клавиши Compose. Гугл говорит, что можно добавить свои определения в `~/.XCompose`. Команда `xev | fgrep "keysym"` показывает названия клавиш в системе.

И вот я написала много интересных определений в `~/.XCompose`, но они не заработали даже после перезагрузки.
Тогда я скопировала их в `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose`, но и это не помогло.

И вот что получается: то, что было определено для русской раскладки в `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose`, например

```
<Multi_key> <Cyrillic_pe> <Cyrillic_a>  : "§"   section # SECTION SIGN
```

работает, то есть <kbd>Compose</kbd>-<kbd>п</kbd>-<kbd>а</kbd> печатает "§",
а те определения, что я добавила, типа

```
<Multi_key> <Cyrillic_be> <Cyrillic_be> : "«" guillemotleft # левая кавычка-ёлочка    
<Multi_key> <Cyrillic_e> <Cyrillic_a>   : "а́" # CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER a WITH COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT
```

не работают!
(Почему-то в Firefoxе знак ударения сдвинулся вправо, но на моем компьютере он на месте).

В данный момент меня беспокоят следующие символы:

- **Кавычки-елочки**.
  <kbd>Multi_key</kbd> <kbd><</kbd> <kbd><</kbd> дает нам "«", а <kbd>Multi_key</kbd> <kbd>></kbd> <kbd>></kbd> — "»".
  С русской клавиатуры ввести это невозможно, потому что нет знаков "<" и ">".
  То есть чтобы ввести кавычки, которые используются в русском, нужно переключиться на английскую раскладку, нажать на клавиши, а потом переключится обратно.
- **Ударение** в русской раскладке получается совсем криво. С Compose не работает, но можно использовать Unicode:

  - переключиться на английский;
  - после буквы, на которую нужно поставить ударение, нажать одновременно <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>u</kbd>. Появится подчеркнутая буква u.
  - ввести "301". Это Unicode знака dead_acute — ударения, которое не сдвигает каретку.
  - <kbd>Ввод</kbd>. Появляется ударение над буквой.
  - поменять язык обратно на русский.

Что я делаю не так с Compose?
Есть ли еще способы добавить символы? Мне нужно, чтобы легко запоминалось и быстро нажималось.

Comment: Отредактируйте ваш вопрос. Получилась каша!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

попробуйте добавить в конец файла `~/.profile` строку:

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE="xim"
```

и перзапустите сеанс.

после этого в программах, использующих *gtk* (например, *firefox*), должно заработать то, что написано в вашем `~/.XCompose`.

---

**обновление**

хотя, вероятно, более «правильно-дистрибутивный» метод — это запустить программу `im-config` (если у неё есть возможность, она «нарисует» *gui-окно*, иначе — текстовое меню), где дойти до выбора вариантов конфигурации *input methods* и выбрать *xim* (этот пункт ближе к концу).

после чего, опять-таки, надо перезапустить сеанс.

Comment: im-config сработал, GTK_IM_MODULE не проверяла.

Comment: в конечном итоге получается то же самое — в переменные окружения gui-программ попадает та самая переменная `GTK_IM_MODULE` с тем самым значением: `xim`

Answer (score 3):

Этот ответ содержит **обновленную информацию для Ubuntu 18.04** и упорядоченные инструкции (на случай. что мне придется делать это еще раз, и я опять все забуду).

### Определяем  клавишу `Compose`.

Прежде всего, нам надо проверить, определена ли клавиша <kbd>Compose</kbd>, и если да. то где.
Нажимаем на значок переключения языка, затем **Показать раскладку клавиатуры**.
Если клавиши <kbd>Compose</kbd> нету, то его можно установить с помощью пакета `gnome tweaks`. ([См.](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html.ru))
(Раньше это делалось через **Параметры → Клавиатура**).
Устанавливаем:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

или

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Либо в **Менеджер приложений Ubuntu** устанавливаем **Доп. настройки  gnome**  (можно написать в поисковой строке `gnome tweaks` и он найдет).

- Запускаем.
- Открываем **Клавиатура и мышь**
- Нажимаем на кнопку  **Композиционная клавиша**  и выбираем, на какую клавишу ее назначить.

Ставим английскую раскладку и проверяем, что клавиша <kbd>Compose</kbd> работает. Например, <kbd>Compose</kbd> - - - должно напечатать длинное тире: —.

### Создаем свои комбинации клавиш.

Свои комбинации определяются в файле `~/.XCompose`.
Как сообщает нам `man XCompose`, мы можем включать в него другие файлы определений командой `include`.
В общем случае лучше всего включить системный файл своей локали:

```
include "%L"
```

Но в нашем случае `/usr/share/X11/locale/ru_RU.UTF-8/Compose` содержит только одну строчку

```
include "/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose"
```

*Примечание.

 Все это сделано плохо. Английский файл содержит определения для кириллических гласных с ударением, вроде*

```
<Multi_key> <apostrophe> <Cyrillic_A>           : "А́"
```

*но пользоваться ими в русской раскладке невозможно, потому что клавиша `<apostrophe>` в русской раскладке превращается в  `<Cyrillic_e>,` она же "э". (В Гугле сказали, что из более 50-ти кириллических языков апостроф существует только в украинском и белорусском.)

Там также есть определение для печати символа "№" с помощью  `<Multi_key>`, но в русской раскладке он и так есть.

Хорошо бы сделать минимальный `/usr/share/X11/locale/ru_RU.UTF-8/Compose` с ударениями над гласными и со всеми русскими кавычками и распространять его вместе с Ubuntu, но я не знаю, как.*

Теперь давайте добавим в  `~/.XCompose` свои определения. Для этого нам нужно узнать названия клавиш в раскладке.
Запускаем команду  `xev | fgrep "keysym"`.
Открывается окошечко. Печатаем туда символы, а в терминале нам показывают их названия.
Например, мы хотим добавить в русскую раскладку квадратные скобки, чтоб было удобнее редактировать свои тексты на stackoverflow.
Нажимаем на клавишу `[` в окошке `xev`. 
В терминале, откуда был запущен `xev`, нам сообщают: `keysym 0x5b, bracketleft`. То есть эта клавиша называется   bracketleft и заодно мы узнали ее юникод U005B.
Выставляем русскую раскладку, печатаем то же самое. Теперь клавиша называется `Cyrillic_ha`.
Добавляем в `~/.XCompose` строчку

```
<Multi_key> <Cyrillic_ha>                       : "["   U005B   # левая квадратная скобка
```

Таким же образом добавляем

```
<Multi_key> <Cyrillic_hardsign>                 : "]"   U005D   # правая квадратная скобка
<Multi_key> <Cyrillic_IO> <exclam>              : "`"   U0027   # апостр́оф (на Multi_key+Ё+!)
```

Мы можем также скопировать готовый `.XCompose`, например, [отсюда](https://github.com/kragen/xcompose) или [отсюда](https://code.google.com/archive/p/ootync-xcompose/).
Они содержат гигантское количество определений комбинаций клавиш.

После изменения `.XCompose` перезапустите сеанс, чтобы увидеть результаты. Добавлять в  `~/.profile` строку  `export GTK_IM_MODULE="xim"` больше не нужно.

Еще полезность:
В `man Compose` написано, что вместо файла `~/.XCompose` можно использовать любой другой файл, и сообщить о нем системе с помощью переменной `$XCOMPOSEFILE`. Как это может пригодиться? Например, у одного пользователя есть классный `~/.XCompose`. Другой пользователь может использовать его, если вставит в свой  `~/.profile` строку

```
export XCOMPOSEFILE="$HOME/../<another_user>/.XCompose"
```

Так у вас есть только одна копия `.XCompose`, которую используют несколько пользователей.

И про **сдвиг ударения**. Оказывается, в нем виноват шрифт Verdana, см. [Хабр](https://habr.com/ru/post/25531/).